# 8 independants mono channel on 7.1 sound card, but possibility to play sound on 8 channels simultaneously

Tags: audio, alsa

For a personal sound project with a raspberry PI 3 and an USB 7.1 channel sound card, I need to use the sound card as 8 independents mono channels, to play different mono sounds on specifics channel. And sometime 2 or more mono sounds car be played (mixed) in the same time on a given channel. I finally found the way to do that in my `.asoundrc` configuration file :

```
pcm_slave.usbsoundcard {
pcm "hw:1"
rate 44100
channels 8
periods 128
period_time 0
period_size 1024
buffer_time 0
buffer_size 4096
}

pcm.ch1 {
type dmix
slave usbsoundcard
ipc_key 1001
bindings [ 0 ]
}

pcm.ch2 {
type dmix
slave usbsoundcard
ipc_key 1001
bindings [ 1 ]
}

pcm.ch3 {
type dmix
slave usbsoundcard
ipc_key 1001
bindings [ 6 ]
}

pcm.ch4 {
type dmix
slave usbsoundcard
ipc_key 1001
bindings [ 7 ]
}

pcm.ch5 {
type dmix
slave usbsoundcard
ipc_key 1001
bindings [ 2 ]
}

pcm.ch6 {
type dmix
slave usbsoundcard
ipc_key 1001
bindings [ 3 ]
}

pcm.ch7 {
type dmix
slave usbsoundcard
ipc_key 1001
bindings [ 4 ]
}

pcm.ch8 {
type dmix
slave usbsoundcard
ipc_key 1001
bindings [ 5 ]
}
```

With this config file, I can play what I want on the channel I want, and I can play multiple sound in same time on each independent channel if needed with commands like this:

```
aplay -D plug:ch3 sound1_mono.wav &
aplay -D plug:ch3 sound2_mono.wav &  # sound 2 mixed with sound 1 on channel 3
aplay -D plug:ch7 sound3_mono.wav &
aplay -D plug:ch8 sound4_mono.wav &
```

etc...

But I want to add another possibility.  I want to add a virtual channel named "all", which must route the played sound on ALL 8 mono channels. The final goal is to configure Asterisk pbx system configured as intercom to use this channel : when called, Asterisk will autoanswer, and I want voice routed (mixed) on all 8 channels of the sound card.

I naively tried that :

```
pcm.all {
type dmix
slave usbsoundcard
ipc_key 1001
bindings [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ]
}
```

But it doesn't work. For testing I also play a mono sound on the 'all' virtual channel.
If I do : aplay -D plug:all sound5_mono.wav
The sound is correctly played on all channel ch1... ch8 where no other wav file is played. 
But on channel where a sound is already played, can't hear sound5_mono. wav but I have crackling noices

How can I write my. asoundrc file to have it working ? 
What I want to do is a kind of audio multiroom : play differents mono file on each channel ch1.... ch8 in differents room, and when I call the raspberry with a SIP phone, voice is played (mixed) in all rooms.

Comment: `dmix` has no channel limit. How exactly are you trying to use `all`?

Comment: Like this : aplay -D plug:all sound.wav ---> the goal is to have the sound mixed on all 8 mono channels ch1... ch8 of the usb sound card.

Comment: In fact I want to build a kind of audio multiroom : 8 different sounds are played on channels 1 to 8 in 8 different rooms. And the virtual channel 'all'  is used by asterisk as an intercom system : I can call the raspberry with a SIP phone, the raspberry autoanswers, and the voice must be played (mixed) in all room.

Comment: How many channels does `sound.wav` have? One? Eight? Please edit the question to specify what exactly should happen with the channels.

Comment: Sound played on ch1 to ch8 can be mono or stereo (thus downmixed to mono, but it seems it's automatic with plug: ). This part already works well with the first config file. Sound on 'all' virtual channel will be played by Asterisk when it will answer calls, I don't know if it's mono or stereo. But if stereo, should be mixed to mono and routed/mixed on all 8 channels ch1 to ch8

Comment: To edit the question, click "edit".

Comment: Done :) With mono files (which is ok for my project), I have another behavior, it almost works :)

Answer (score 1):

even if your last proposition doesn't work for virtual channel "all", it helped me a lot, and I tried something which works perfectly on my computer, with the same USB sound card.

Here is the config file :

```
pcm.dmix8 {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1001
    slave {
        pcm "hw:2"
        rate 44100
        channels 8
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 32768
    } }

pcm.ch1 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm dmix8
    ttable.0.0 1 }

pcm.ch2 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm dmix8
    ttable.0.1 1 }

pcm.ch3 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm dmix8
    ttable.0.6 1 }

pcm.ch4 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm dmix8
    ttable.0.7 1 }

pcm.ch5 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm dmix8
    ttable.0.4 1 }

pcm.ch6 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm dmix8
    ttable.0.5 1 }

pcm.ch7 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm dmix8
    ttable.0.6 1 }

pcm.ch8 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm dmix8
    ttable.0.7 1 }

pcm.all {
    type plug
    slave.pcm dmix8
    ttable.0.0 1
    ttable.0.1 1
    ttable.0.2 1
    ttable.0.3 1
    ttable.0.4 1
    ttable.0.5 1
    ttable.0.6 1
    ttable.0.7 1 }
```

With this config file, everything works as expected !! The channel "all" is used by Asterisk as a local softphone, and ch1...ch8 are used to play different mono sounds in 8 different rooms.
And when I call Asterisk, it auto-answers and I can hear the voice in the 8 HP, mixed with existing sound of the room :)

Thank you very much for your help !

Next step, try on my raspberry PI 3 board, but no reason to have a different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can use different `dmix` definitions with the same `ipc_key`; it might be a better idea to use a common `dmix` device.

To be able to play a stero file to all channels, you have to convert it to mono first.

```perl
pcm.dmix8 {
    type dmix
    slave {
        pcm "hw:1"
        rate 44100
        channels 8
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 32768
    }
}

pcm.ch1 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm dmix8
    ttable.0.0 1
}
pcm.ch2 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm dmix8
    ttable.0.1 1
}
# and so on with "ttable.0.x 1"

pcm.all {
    type plug
    slave {
        pcm {
            type route
            slave.pcm dmix8
            ttable [ [ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ] ]
        }
        channels 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I added an ipc_key in pcm.dmix8, if not present I have an error (ALSA lib pcm_direct.c:1707:

(snd1_pcm_direct_parse_open_conf) Unique IPC key is not defined).

And changed channels to 2 to try on my computer. 
ch1 and ch2 works as expected. But when playing a mono file to "all", there is an error : 

ALSA lib pcm_params.c:2162:(snd1_pcm_hw_refine_slave) Slave PCM not usable
aplay: set_params:1204: Configuration erronée pour ce périphérique PCM: pas de configuration